# facing issues with htaccess in subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have created a subdomain but when i am visiting it in browser its giving 500 internal server error.

Subdomain: sub.domain.com
Directory: /sub

Below is the htaccess file on /:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] 
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Do I need to add anything in my htaccesss file to make it work.

Update:----------------------------------

Also My main domain is working fine, no problem in that.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # NOTE: change this to your actual StatusNet base URL path,
 # minus the domain part:
 #
    http://sub.domain.com/        => /
    http://sub.domain.com/mublog/ => /mublog/
 #
 RewriteBase /mublog/

## Uncomment these if having trouble with API authentication
## when PHP is running in CGI or FastCGI mode.
#
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
#RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ini)">
 Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing order of your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteRule !^app/webroot/ app/webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you're still getting 500 for subdomain then post .htaccess for subdomain.

Comment: please check this again. Thanks